# Is there any alternate utility to VMware converter to host VM faster?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-converter, utilities

we are using ESXi 4.0 and ESXi 4.1.

I am using VMware converter to host my VM in our ESXi server.

As our VM size is 35 GB , it is taking half a day to host it.

Is there any alternate utility to VMware converter to host VM faster?

Comment: Do you mean a faster way to convert  from physical to Virtual?

Comment: @Lucas Kauffman: I am using VMware converter to copy my VM to ESXi server. I thought VMware converter utility was slow to host a machine to ESXi server. so i asked is there any other way(May be some other utility other than  VMware converter) to host a VM which is faster than Vmware converter?

Answer (score 2):

You have a bottleneck somewhere. That bottleneck is likely one of these three:

1. Disk IO on the source system
2. Network between source and target
3. Disk IO on the target system

You'll need to investigate which of these is the case and then take action accordingly.

Comment: Generic canned answer for a pretty vague question. You could have at least contributed something like a how to on doing the investigation.